# Witt dimension formula for free Lie Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, lie-algebras

I was trying to understand the proof of the Witt dimension formula for free Lie algebras. I was basically following this proof.

(I'm not posting the complete proof but just the piece where I'm currently stuck on.)

> How do we prove the Witt dimension formula?
>   Write $\ell_n = \dim L_n$.
>   In each homogeneous subspace $L_n$ of the free Lie algebra choose an ordered basis $\{ f_{n1}, \dotsc, f_{n \ell_n} \}$.
>   Put these finite bases together into an infinite ordered basis of $L$:
>   $$
>   f_{11}, \dotsc, f_{1 \ell_1},
>   f_{21}, \dotsc, f_{2 \ell_2},
>   f_{31}, \dotsc, f_{3 \ell_3},
>   \dotsc
> $$
>   For simplicity write this last basis as
>   $$
>   g_1, g_2, g_3, \dotsc, g_i, \dotsc
> $$
>   The **PBW Theorem** (after Poincaré, Birkhof and Witt) states that a basis for $A$ consists of all products of the form
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{1}
>   g_{i_1} g_{i_2} \dotsm g_{i_k}
>   \qquad
>   (i_1 \leq i_2 \leq \dotsb \leq i_k).
> \end{equation}
>   Now we need to do some combinatorics.
>   There are $\ell_d$ Lie polynomials $g_i$ of degree $d$.
>   Each $g_i$ contributes degree $d$ to the total degree of the associative word in $(1)$.
>   But each $g_i$ may occur any number $k$ of times (consecutively) in $(1)$.
>   The generating function for the contribution of these $k$ elements of degree $d$ to the total degree of $(1)$ is
>   $$
>     1 + x^d + x^{2d} + \dotsb + x^{kd} + \dotsb
>   = \frac{1}{1-x^d} \cdotp
> $$
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVc73.png).)

But I do not understand the meaning of the last 4 lines. Why isn't the total contribution to the degree of $(1)$ just $dk$? Where that generating function comes from? What is $x$ in that formula?

Unfortunately this seems to be the most clear proof of the Witt's formula I've found.

Comment: I didn't ask for the meaning of the words. I asked to understand them in the context of the proof. For example, how to deduce the that generating formula from the above lines? Clearly $x$ is a variable, but why is there? What are the values it can assume?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738157/generating-function-for-the-partition-function); the *coefficients* (not the variable) give the numbers you are looking for, in this case $p(n)$. One can do the same for Witt's formula (see wiki proof for necklace polynomials).

Comment: There are many references for a proof of Witt's formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lie_algebra). Most of them are really easy to understand. The PBW theorem itself might be more difficult, which you are using.